# SSIS Excel -Retrieving minimum date value and storing it into a variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an Excel Source which has got 1000 rows with some 10 columns  and one of the column is a Date Field ,We have to retrieve the minimum date value and assign it to a variable in ssis .Could you guys provide me a script or steps to map that value to the variable...So that i can use it in control flow task to perform truncate operation using the variable value.
please adviiiise

your help in this regard is appreciated.
Rosh..

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple: you use an Execute SQL Task to retrieve the value and store it in a variable.
Basic steps:

A. Create an Excel Connection Manager, point it at your file

B. Create a variable to store the value

C. Add an Execute SQL Task

1. Connection type: EXCEL
2. Specify connection manager
3. ResultSet: single row
4. SQLSourceType: Direct input
5. SQLStatement: `select max(fieldname) as fieldname from [sheetname$]`

In the result set tab, add a row with the the ResultName set to `fieldname`, and the earlier created variable in the Variable Name column.

Note that the sheetname qualification (square brackets) is necessary because of the required `$`.  If your field (column) contains a space in the name, you have to also qualify it: `[field name]`

Comment: Hi wat to do if my file is csv? and i want to use that max(value) variable inside data to truncate table before i load my data..DataFlow is Pretty simple source is csv file i need to load this into oledb befor loading into db i shud check the maximum date value and i wil truncate table with condition delete from table where date<=maximum date variable and load the db with source file....please help!

Comment: In that case it's a totally different solution - would have been better if you'd specified CSV instead of Excel in your question.  In this case, you need to use a data flow and filter the records in there - there's a ton of examples online for this case